# Choosing a listbox from multiple list boxes

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am somewhat new to excel vba and I am in search of an answer on how to choose a list box by using a variable.
For instance the code I found is as follows:

```
Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.LB_JobList.List(iCtr)
```

Instead of `ListBox2` I would like the 2 to be another number selected by the user from a combo box.

Current code is:

```
FrameNumber = CMB_FrameNumber.Value 'number selected by user
lb = ("ListBox" & FrameNumber) 'this would = ListBox#
```

Therefore I would like something similar to

```
Me.lb.AddItem Me.LB_JobList.List(iCtr)
```

Comment: You can use `Me.controls("ListBox" & FrameNumber)`

Comment: Thank you SJR.  It worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment above is good, but if you want to do something a little safer (in case you have more numbers available than controls, say), you could loop through the available controls and check against their name.

```
For Each contr In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(contr) = "ListBox" And contr.Name = ("ListBox" & FrameNumber) Then
        lb = contr
    End If
Next
```